# Query to retrieve data of specific date in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access

I want to retrieve of particular date. For example my database has data from 1st-Jan to 31-AUG. I want to fetch data of 1st two months. Please suggest me helping query for this purpose thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the query design window, add your table, double-click fields to add them to the grid. Type a date into the criteria line underneath the date field you added.

Answer (score 0):

SQL query: 
select * 
from table
where table.my_date <= #29/02/2012#

will filter date before 29 feb. In query window you can type <=#29/02/2012#